# Python Would it be possible to fill a dictionary with multiple keys and values using one string?

Tags: python, string, testing, dictionary

**The point is not to use dict.copy(), and if you want you can view this as a challenge.**
I have this dict for example, and I transform it into a string

```
Dict = {'Hello':'World', 'Hi':'Again'}
x = str(Dict)
```

x is the variable containing the string.
Now i want to put x in a dictionary, BUT i must be able to print individual keys ('Hello' and 'Hi') as well as the values ('World' and 'Again')

```
Dict2 = {x}
for key, value in Dict2.items() :
    print (key, value)
```

This doesn't work and I know why. 
The output of :

```
for key, value in Dict2.items() :
        print (key, value)
```

Must be the same as :

```
for key, value in Dict.items() :
        print (key, value)
```

Comment: I'm not sure you are aware but Dictionaries are unordered so if you print out the content of the dict later, you wouldn't know what you'd get, could very well be `Hi again Hello World`

Comment: As long as you can print the keys and values independently it's fine

Comment: If you think you have a need for this in a piece of code you are writing, then you need to re-think your problem - as mentioned, dictionaries are unordered. You could do this using ordered dictionaries, and maybe subclassing it to provide functions to parse a string, and output as a simple string - but I don't see why you would want to.

Comment: I don't need it particularly, I set myself a challenge and I'm stuck. any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that `Dict2 = {x}` doesn't do what you want.

```
>>> Dict = {'hello':'world', 'hi':'again'}
>>> x = str(Dict)
>>> x
"{'hi': 'again', 'hello': 'world'}"
>>> Dict2 = {x}
>>> Dict2
set(["{'hi': 'again', 'hello': 'world'}"])
```

As you can see it converts it to a set.
To create a dict from a string you can and should use [ast.literal_eval()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast-helpers):

```
>>> import ast
>>> d = ast.literal_eval("{'hello': 'world', 'hi': 'again'}")
>>> d
{'hi': 'again', 'hello': 'world'}
>>> type(d)
<type 'dict'>
```

---

As pointed out by Antti Haapala

*Note that `ast.literal_eval` only works for a strict subset of values; furthermore, `str(dict)` is not guaranteed to be lossless at all, as it uses `__repr__` for keys and values.*

Comment: Note that `ast.literal_eval` only works for a strict subset of values; furthermore, `str(dict)` is not guaranteed to be lossless at all, as it uses `__repr__` for keys and values.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I was just working with the example from the OP, I will add your note nonetheless because it's a good note

Comment: Yeah, this was just comment for the OP